# C++ dynamic instantiation using macro

Tags: c++, macros, preprocessor

I'm trying to achieve dynamic instantiation in C++, which I mean, creating instances from strings of class. But after some digging, I found that it seems C++ does not natively support a feature like this.

For example, I have an "Interface" named `Person`, and some concrete implementations like `Worker`, `Teacher`, `Programmer` etc. In C++, if I want to store all of the implementations into a map `collection`, I have to write something like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

#include "Worker.hpp"
#include "Teacher.hpp"
#include "Programmer.hpp"
// ...

using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<string, Person*> collection;
    Worker worker;
    Teacher teacher;
    Programmer monkey;
    // ...

    collection[worker->title] = &worker;
    collection[teacher->title] = &teacher;
    collection[monkey->tittle] = &monkey;
    // ... 
}
```

It seems okay, but I don't like to change three places in code each time I add a job title.
What I would like to do looks like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include "Worker.hpp"
#include "Teacher.hpp"
#include "Programmer.hpp"
# ...

using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<string, Person*> collection;
    char titles[][20] = {"Worker", "Teacher", "Programmer"};

    for (auto const &Title: titles) {
        // this is the magic I would like to have.
        Title object;
        collection[title] = &object;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no magic in C++.

So after a while, I realize that there is macro and the preprocessor, maybe I can go around with that. And this is what I can come up with so far:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "Worker.hpp"
#include "Teacher.hpp"
#include "Programmer.hpp"
# ...

#define PUSH(name)\
name o_##name;\
collection[o_##name.title] = &o_##name;\

using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<string, Person*> collection;
    PUSH(Worker);
    PUSH(Teacher);
    PUSH(Programmer);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to automate the `#include` directive but it seems macro do not have the concept of variable. and the preprocessor does not interpret the macro twice.

Any idea how I can achieve something similar?

I know it sounds silly to dig my head into something this futile but it's just my characteristic I can't get rid of this idea if it hasn't been prove right or wrong.

I'd very much appreciate an advice.

Edit:

Thanks for all your efforts to help me. I was a bit unclear on the question. What I actually wanted to implement is that

**I wanted to create many pieces of programs and let the user to decide what to run. The potential problem is that, I might end up having tons of `if-else` statement to let user to decide what to run, because I wanted to write tons of small pieces of code in the project.**

I'm not sure if I make myself clear this time. But I've already given up the idea, and using a testing framework to do the job.

Thank you all again.

Comment: *Unfortunately, there is no magic in C++.* Says someone who has clearly never been cursed by nasal demons.

Comment: It kinda looks like [Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) or [Abstract Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) might be of use to you.

Comment: I advise against automating the includes. It generally leads to confusion, but the specific headers can, probably should, be hidden inside the implementation file that houses the Factory an makes the instances.

Comment: @user4581301 LOL, thank you for your advice. I'll carve that on my mind. But I think Factory is kinda over-killed. I still have to modify the Factory when I need to add an implementation, right? What I actually trying to achieve, is to run a program by the name user specified. Maybe it's kinda naive but I don't like to use if-else or switch statement. I like to make things automative. Like if I create a class, it just magically be included into the program and runs. And as I'm typing, I just realized that the shared library can probably be an option. I'll dig into that. Thank you again.

Comment: One thing you can do is make a class that in its constructor adds the value to the registry. Then in each of Worker.cpp, Programmer.cpp, Teacher.cpp you can do something like `AutoRegisterClass<Worker> autoRegister;` (`AutoRegisterClass` being the class template you made for the trick)

Comment: What if each class in the hierarchy registers its own factory function with the master factory? Then you could call `MasterFactory("programmer", "monkey");` and Master Factory looks up `"programer"`'s factory function and calls it with `"monkey"`. Voila! One `Programmer` named `"monkey"`. Errr. Yeah. What he ^ just said.

Comment: It looks like you want dynamic allocation of objects. Look up `make_unique` and `make_shared`.

Comment: @immibis Do you mean that I include each implementation and when I do that, they register themselves to the AutoRegisterClass?

Comment: @user4581301 I don't know but isn't class definition should be only definition? Calling MasterFactory constructor in class file violates some best practice I think. I just don't feel it right. or have I got it wrong?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Sorry, I don't think I am able to use `make_unique` and `make_shared` to achieve what I want to. Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: I'm sorry guys, my English is not good, I'm having issues reading English documentations. They give me headaches. Could you please provide a simple example? I'd really appreciate your time.

Comment: What is the lifetime of the collection in the application?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Eternity I suppose :) . I wanted to make a global variable but IDE complains about it so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear on type relationships, lifetimes, etc., but the following code is probably in the main direction of what you're asking for.

The idea is to use dynamically allocated objects, and a smart pointer such as `shared_ptr` to manage their lifetimes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>              // std::(multimap>
#include <memory>           // std::(make_shared, shared_ptr)
#include <stdlib.h>         // rand, srand
#include <string>
#include <time.h>           // time    
using namespace std;

class Person
{
    string  m_name;

public:
    auto name() const -> string { return m_name; }
    virtual auto profession() const -> string { return ""; }

    Person( const string& name ): m_name( name ) {}
    virtual ~Person() = default;
};

class Worker:
    public Person
{
public:
    auto profession() const -> string override { return "Worker"; }
    Worker( const string& name ): Person( name ) {}
};

class Teacher:
    public Worker
{
public:
    auto profession() const -> string override { return "Teacher"; }
    Teacher( const string& name ): Worker( name ) {}
};

class Programmer:
    public Worker
{
public:
    auto profession() const -> string override { return "Programmer"; }
    Programmer( const string& name ): Worker( name ) {}
};

using Profession_map = multimap<string, shared_ptr<Person>>;

void add_to( Profession_map& persons, const shared_ptr<Person> someone )
{
    persons.emplace( someone->profession(), someone );
};

void list( const Profession_map& persons, const string& profession )
{
    const string profession_description = ( 0?""
        : profession == ""?         "Unknown profession person"
        : profession == "Worker"?   "Generic worker"
        :                           profession
        );

    const int n_registered = persons.count( profession );
    if( n_registered == 1 )
    {
        cout << "There is 1 " << profession_description;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "There are " << n_registered << " " << profession_description << "s";
    }
    if( n_registered > 0 )
    {
        cout << ": ";
        const auto registered = persons.equal_range( profession );
        int i = 0;
        for( auto it = registered.first; it != registered.second; ++it, ++i )
        {
            if( it != registered.first ) { cout << (i == n_registered - 1? " and " : ", "); }
            const shared_ptr<Person> p_person = it->second;
            cout << p_person->name();
        }
    }
    cout << "." << endl;
}

auto main()
    -> int
{
    Profession_map persons;

    srand( time( nullptr ) );       // Seed for rand() sequence.
    for( const string& name : {"alfa", "beta", "charlie", "delta", "echo", "foxtrot"} )
    {
        switch( rand() % 4 )
        {
            case 0:     add_to( persons, make_shared<Person>( name ) ); break;
            case 1:     add_to( persons, make_shared<Worker>( name ) ); break;
            case 2:     add_to( persons, make_shared<Teacher>( name ) ); break;
            case 3:     add_to( persons, make_shared<Programmer>( name ) ); break;
        }
    }

    list( persons, "" );
    list( persons, "Worker" );
    list( persons, "Teacher" );
    list( persons, "Programmer" );
}
```

Comment: @EricYoung also read up on move semantics. Together with Smart Pointers they significantly change how you should program in C++.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for advice. I have finished them all. But still could figure out how to implement them here. Maybe I was unclear what I really want to implement.

Answer (score 1):

C++ has magic and it is called templates.

You can use something like this...

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>


template<class T> 
struct make_object {
    static_assert(std::is_convertible<T*, Person*>::value, "Object must be derived from Person");
    T* object;
    make_object() : object(new T) {}
};


//** For iterating over the tuple and inserting each person into the collection
template<std::size_t I = 0, class MAP, typename... Tp>
inline typename std::enable_if<I == sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
insertPeople(MAP& collection, std::tuple<Tp...>& t)
{ }

template<std::size_t I = 0, class MAP, typename... Tp>
inline typename std::enable_if<I < sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
    insertPeople(MAP& collection, std::tuple<Tp...>& t)
{
    auto object = std::get<I>(t).object;
    collection[object->title] = object;
    insertPeople<I + 1, MAP, Tp...>(collection, t);
}

//** Creates the tuple containing the objects
template<class... CLASSES>
void createPeople(std::map<std::string, Person*>& collection)
{
    std::tuple<make_object<CLASSES>...> objects;
    insertPeople(collection, objects);
}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, Person*> collection;
    createPeople<Worker, Teacher, Progammer>(collection);
    for (auto person : collection)
        std::cout << person.second->title << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Don't forget to delete all the objects when you are done. Alternatively, you could use unique/shared pointers.

Comment: This is too advanced C++, I'm a newbie :'(  I know about templates, but I don't recognize a lot of syntax and functions of you code. I'll definitely try after I finish my intermediate C++ course. Thank you. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Eric: Better to try to get your head around templates rather than trying to create an unreadable and unmaintainable macro "magic". :-) Good luck!

Comment: @rici Thanks. I did. and it helps.